# Methodology for data transform that best fits normal

Tags: data-transformation, normal-distribution

SAS EM has a node that generates the transformation for a dataset that makes it best fit a normal distribution. I can't imagine the people at SAS are the only ones to figure out how to do this. Is there any documentation out there on methodologies that do the same? Or an open source implementation?

Comment: "The" "best-fit" transformation is the inverse cumulative normal integral of the percentiles (readily computed with almost anything more sophisticated than an adding machine), but I doubt this is what you are referring to.  For this problem to be well-posed, you need to stipulate (a) what family of transformations you have in mind and (b) how to measure the goodness of fit.  You are correct that this problem has been addressed, but as you might guess, it has many different solutions depending on what is assumed in (a) and (b).

Comment: I'm assuming you're doing this so that your data might meet the assumptions of standard least-squares statistics - regression, ANOVA, etc.  Be careful here, though.  Make sure you know what the transformed values actually mean lest your inferences are wrong.  Similarly, there may be meaning in the non-normality of your data.  Perhaps a generalized linear model might be more appropriate for you.

Comment: By 'SAS EM' do you mean SAS Enterprise Miner or the SAS implementation of the Expectation-Maximization algorithm?

Comment: @onestop By SAS EM I mean Enterprise Miner. @jebyrnes In this case I'm looking at variables to be used in a clustering analysis. But in general I don't like to use techniques that I don't have a basic understanding of.

Comment: @whuber for (b) KS seems natural enough. There's also quantile matching. (a) I would think some linear combination of exponentiation, log, and taking to various powers, with a penalty for complexity. But I do think the details are putting the cart in front of the horse. What I want is a general discussion of the topic that may have its own recommendations for answers to your questions.

Comment: Asking *"How should I best transform my variable?"* without telling us what model you're using is meaningless. I'm going to go ahead and take the liberty of tagging this [tag:least-squares], [tag:regression], [tag:ANOVA], and if that's wring, please update it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The classical transformations include the log, sqrt, and inverse (1/Y) transformations. More sophisticated transformations include the power transformation, from which the Box-Cox optimization chooses a particular transformation which optimized a log-likelihood. Which transformation to use is almost becoming a lost art form, but there is an excellent book by A. C. Atkinson (1985) called *Plots, Transformations, and Regression* that talks about how to analyze your data and decide how to transform it. For example, the book discusses special transformations for data that are proportions.

Comment: Rick, thanks  for the book, but sadly GoogleBooks gives only [few words](http://books.google.com/books?ei=dcWoTqavB4_1-ga24qy5Dw&ct=result&id=L1SqAAAAIAAJ&dq=Plots%2C+Transformations%2C+and+Regression+An+Introduction+to+Graphical+Methods+of+Diagnostic+Regression+Analysis+A.+C.+Atkinson&q=percentages#search_anchor&safe=high)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the Box–Cox transformation or other sort of [power transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform)?

Comment: This combined with Log likelihood seems to work